# Access data array in Kendo template

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, kendo-mobile

I have a Kendo mobile view that takes data in the form of a JSON feed, and then displays it using a Kendo template.

I want to create a fairly complex grid out of this JSON feed, and the only way I can think to do that is to wrap certain items in a `div` with a class name that varies depending on its position in the array.

**How can I access the array object inside a Kendo template?**

[The docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) give this example:

> For example, to display a list of items using JavaScript and Kendo UI templates, we use the following syntax:

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <ul>
    # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
        <li>#= data[i] #</li>
    # } #
    </ul>
</script>
```

If I do a console.log like this within my template:

```
# console.log(data); #
```

I can see that `data` does reference the JSON, but it's not usable (`data.length`) returns undefined, so that example does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating the JSON object like a list.  It's an object.

```
var count = Object.keys(data).length;
alert(count);
```

So we know that Object.keys(data).length counts all of the keys.  So its stand to reason we can select those keys individually.  Object.keys(data)[i].  You can loop over it and wrap it with an IF for every 2n+2 items.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        # this will do something for every even element
    };
}
```

I would suggest wrapping everything with a class (so no if statement).  And then using the CSS selector 2n+2 (if you're trying to accomplish something with CSS).

Comment: Thanks - I kinda knew I was missing something basic, but I find the Kendo docs are often impenetrable/out-of-date. It just seems like accessing the array within a template should be very simple. What's the best way to post a sample object if I have a reference to it in the console (apologies for such a terrible question)?

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez  You can just console.log(data); or you can JSON.stringify(data); or even console.dir(data);

Comment: @CherryFlavourPez  Yeah the method I gave you will work.  It basically returns the size of the object (9 in this case).

Comment: Ok, so if I do `data.toJSON();` I get the array I was expecting (which is not what the docs say, and seems odd as it would seem that's already being done at some point...). So thank you very much. How then would I, for example, wrap every 2n+2 item in a specific class?

Comment: Cheers - perfect. I need the loop because what I'm trying to achieve (unfortunately) can't be done through CSS alone. I'll have to wrap multiple items in a single div. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use CSS selector nth-child.

```
div:nth-child(2n){
 ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the layout I am trying to achieve means that I need to wrap multiple items in a class (can't be done with CSS alone). I need to access the array.